# My left join return more rows than expected

Tags: sql-server

Why does my left join return more rows than I expected? I tried an inner join but it returns more of rows as well.

```
Select h, b, c 
From table1 t
Left join table2 f On table1.a = table2.g
```

Comment: Well - please explain **what you expected**, and what you got instead..... also please show sample data for the two tables, and the result

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you expected, e.g. "For every row in table1, I expect 1 or fewer matching rows in table2"?

Comment: I expected rows that are equal to table1 before performing the join. 1 to 1 relationship

Comment: ..but we don't know what `t.a` and `f.g` are, how they are related,are they primary keys, are they related via a one-to-one or one-to-many relationship etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Either your join is logically incorrect or there is a 1:M relationship from table1 to table2.

Answer (score 1):

INNER JOIN: returns rows when there is a match in both tables.

LEFT JOIN: returns all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table.

Comment: Yes. Very true. But both type of joins seem to return more rows than expected. The OP wants to know how that is possible. (The inner join might perhaps return somewhat less rows than the left join, but the result may still contain more rows than expected.)

Answer (score 1):

So knowing that you expected a **one-to-one** relationship, my guess (as others have said) is that there's actually a **one-to-many** relationship.

So you need a way to test for that:

```
select table2.g, count(*)
from table2
group by table2.g
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Yes. And if a 1:1 relationship should be enforced, a UNIQUE constraint/index might be created on column `g` of `table2` (apart from the presumably already existing foreign key constraint). Of course, that will only work if your test query for duplucates will not return any results. (Any existing duplicates should be resolved first.)